# android release apk bigger than debug apk

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, minify

I'm using proguard to reduce my apk size. The debug apk reduce from 90mb to 55mb, but the signed apk is 71mb. Here is my build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

signingConfigs {
    XXXX {
        keyAlias 'xxxx'
        keyPassword 'xxxx'
        storeFile file('/Users/xxxx.jks')
        storePassword 'xxxxxx'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 61
    versionName "4.1.8.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.XXXX

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.XXXX
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.XXXX
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
}
```

and

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        name "jcenter"
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using instant run for debug?

Comment: Note that ProGuard only processes class files whereas in the screenshots it is apparent that the resources different between the two versions. The release apk has many more drawables. Is it possible that you have additional dependencies for the release type?

Comment: I didn't use instant run @MohammedAtif.

Comment: @T.Neidhart yes, The release apk has many more drawables. But I don't know why, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @T.Neidhart release but not signed also 55mb, but if I signed it increased to 71mb.

Comment: @Thinsky did u get the solution? I am having same problem, debug apk size is 10mb and release apk size is 19mb, i am using latest version of android studio

Comment: @AnantShah sorry, I didn't get any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Further explaining [sosite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088250/3126052), it seems that this happens only if comparing a `debug` apk built via Run or Debug meant for a specific device (even without Instant Run enabled) instead of a `debug`apk built via Build > Build APK (for any supported device).

Any variant (even `debug` itself) built via *Build APK* will include all the resources for that variant. Also, the *Run/Debug* apk includes pre-dexed classes specific for that single device, while *Build APK* ones includes only some general pre-dexed classes that the compiler determines safe for all supported devices - the full dexing only occurs in the device itself, when the apk is installed.

I've zipdiff-ed an apk generated via *Debug* with another via *Build APK* for the same variant of the same project and [published the simplified output](https://pastebin.com/y1GvKv72) for demonstration ([also available as html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9sAa_wAR-Q3bXVQa0gwYWZ6Y3M)).

Answer (score 1):

When you build your app locally for specific type of phone then Android Studio attach only necessary resource files. When you build release version then you have attached all types of drawables so you app file size can increase drastically.

I suggest you to use jpg in place of png in as many places as you can and compress them of course - often I use [tinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) website or just Photoshop ;)