# App size increased in Release build compared to debug build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In all my previous projects debug build always bigger & release build smaller.

But strange issue occur for me. 
When I build the debug APK it have **1085KB**

If I build the release APK it have **2432KB**

Any one give me solution for this issue.

My dependencies in build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ranjih.kotlinandroid"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile project(path: ':lib')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of image resources in your app? Android Studio may not be packaging all resolutions in debug builds.

Comment: @Jonathan727 I am not having lot of images. But I have more HTML files in assets folder.  My doubt is app compat dependency. Is this dependency increase app size?

Comment: I recommend testing as @Moonbloom suggests and generate two release APKs, one with and one without minify. `buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled false} releaseMinify { minifiyEnabled true } }`

Comment: Also, please post your entire build.gradle file for your app

Comment: @Jonathan727 If I give **{ release { minifyEnabled false}}** it generated 3764KB. But I don't  know why debug build takes less size. Full gradle file added.

Comment: That's a completely different question to the one titled above. I think @Moonbloom has answered the original question. Your new question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636182/android-release-apk-bigger-than-debug-apk)

Comment: Also, if your app supports a Wear app, the release build may embed the Wear app's APK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing without for debug builds and with for release builds, that's simply a no-go.

Test with the same build variant.

I've always had the same or lower APK size when enabling minify and shrinkResources.

Libraries can define different resources depending on build type, so one of them might need take up more space when built for release than it does for debug.

Otherwise try and decompile the APK's using Android Studio's built-in tool and see what is taking up all that space.

Comment: yes when I debug build it larger than release build. Reason for this issue I am not build the apk. Just run the project & it generated APK automatically (tested with this) and confused :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting the debug apk generated by Android Studio when you try to Run or Debug the app in a device/emulator, it seems that this apk only packages the resources/dependencies for that specific device specs.

Try going with Build > Build APK, you will probably notice that the (supposedly) same debug apk will be bigger, and probably even so than the release one.

I've also [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285808/3126052) with more details on why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a large png files existed try to use next:

```
android {
    …
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs true // or false
        }
    }
}
```