# Android Studio Install vs. Google Play Install (App Size on Device)

Tags: android, storage

I seem to be having a problem with limiting the size of my installed Android Application. During development I used Android Studio to deploy my application to my testing device. The app took a total of 2.32 MB in storage when freshly installed.

The problem in size came up when I published my application to the Google Play Store for alpha testing. I uninstalled the same app I had loaded with Android Studio, then downloaded the one I listed on the Google Play Store. The funny thing is that the same app now takes up 4.11 MB in storage.

How did this occur? The testing environment is the same, therefore what additional libraries or information would need to be added to the app causing it to take up the extra 1.79 MB?

### TL;DR

- App installed on testing device via Android Studio: 2.32 MB in storage
- Same app installed on the same testing device through the Google Play Store: 4.11 MB in storage

Why is there such a significant increase in the size of my application? No other variables aside from installation source have changed.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409139/why-does-my-app-size-on-device-differ-than-the-apk-or-play-store-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because compiling & installing app into one target device and all devices is different.

When you click the run button, you are targeting only single device.

When deploying a signed release apk, you are targeting all screen densities, intel and arm processors. It includes extra files. It makes your apk file bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this existing answer on SO. [Android release apk bigger than debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636182/android-release-apk-bigger-than-debug-apk)

The answers point out how a debug version only includes resources for the connected devices screen density.  For production all images/res are included.  Also, you should be able to further reduce size of your apk by using pro guard if you aren't already.